# Error(7,56): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'RACE.Race_location'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a trigger that references a table within my sql code. If there is a more simple way than using a trigger please let me know :) But i seem to be getting this error and i can't for the life of me work out why. Everything is named correctly, i have double and tripple checked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RACEDATECHECK 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RACE 
REFERENCING NEW AS RACE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE meet_end_date DATE;
BEGIN
 SELECT EndDate INTO meet_end_date FROM MEETING WHERE :RACE."Race_location" =                 
MEETING."Meeting_Location" AND   :RACE.Meeting_start = MEETING.StartDate;
 IF :RACE."Race_Date" > meet_end_date
 THEN   
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Error, race date must
     fit between meeting parameters');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I also get this error 'Error(8,6): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'RACE.Race_Date''

Comment: Try removing the quotes from "Race_location" and "Meeting_Location". Are you sure that this select statement will always return one row? If it doesn't that will definitely break your trigger at run-time...

Comment: Wow... Deleting the quotation marks fixed all the errors :) Thank you!